# Laravel how to retrieve the recently uploaded values

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, rdbms

I have a database in mysql.  I upload a set of data to the database table from a .csv file or .xls file.  During retrieval I need to retrieve only the set of values which I have recently uploaded to the table in the database. I should not get all the values which stored in the table.(only values recently uploaded to the table should be retrieved).  How can I do that using Laravel?

Comment: Do you want to achieve this during the same request?

Comment: Not in the same request

Comment: Use `insertGetId` method to retrieve the recently added records into DB. Check *Auto-Incrementing IDs* section from [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)

In the table where you store the data from CSV and XML, using a migration, create a flag to mark the records you didn't process yet, e.g. `is_processed`. Give it the default value of `0`.

(2)

If you have data you already retrieved (processed), set those to `1`, so they don't get processed again. You can do this manually with a query, based on the conditions that make sense in your case.

(3)

Then, after you store new data, they will be automatically set to `is_processed = 0`. This means you can identify them afterwards, like this:

```
$unprocessedData = MyModel::where('is_processed', 0)->get();
```

You can also order them if you need to, but - in general - that's the approach I would take.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a table/model named Users;

```
$getLatestUsers=Users::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(5)->get();
```

this will take 5 recent records from database.

Comment: The problem I have is the number of recent records is unknown. It depends on the values that .xls or .csv has

Comment: pk use timestamp column then; ->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(10)->toDateTimeString())

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi I do back that approach

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on what you consider "recent" but you could tweak a function like this to fit your needs:

```
->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString())
```

This would retrieve the elements created the last 5 minutes, but Carbon offers a wide variety of [substractors](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub).

PD: Remember to add `use Carbon\Carbon;` under your namespace declaration.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$latest= Users::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10)->get();

this will return 10 recent values
```